# aws-amplify graphql subscription stops working after connection lost

Tags: angular, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am using aws-amplify and aws-amplify-angular in an Ionic App. I am using to GraphQl Subscriptions to get real time event updates from backend. Whenever I have even a couple seconds of lost connection (airplane mode) the subscriptions stop working completely. I tried unsubscribing and subscribing again but then I get this error

> AWSAppSyncRealTimeProvider.js:333 WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.

Apparently the socket's connection die away even after a second of lost connection, this happens inside the aws-amplify AWSAppSyncRealTimeProvider, so there is not much I can do about it. I am not able to resubscribe after 5mins (default timeout settings) which by the way, there is no way to set/change either.

Anyone having this issue?